# Sum of digits of a number..TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I know this has been asked before, but I am hitting an error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

```
def digitsum(number):
    numlst = list(map(int, str(number)))
    total = sum(numlst)
    return total
x=123
print(digitsum(x))
```

Comment: Did you call a variable `int` elsewhere in the program?

Comment: Error at which line? There is nothing wrong with the posted code.

Comment: If you run only the code you posted it works fine, the problem is elsewhere in your code, you possible named a variable as `int`.

Comment: Error at line 3 ```total = sum(numlst)``` and I haven't used int or sum before

Comment: OK, did you call a variable `sum` elsewhere in the program? And is that variable an `int`?

Comment: @quasar255, `print(sum)` before that line and it prints an integer. Clearly this is not the whole code you have.

Comment: please check the image attached for complete code.

Comment: @quasar255 Have you done Austin's suggestion and put `print(sum)` before the erroring line to see what is in `sum`?

Comment: just did ```print(sum)``` before ```sum```. prints nothing, and same error. this is confusing.

Comment: It prints *nothing*? PLEASE update your question with the actual, full traceback that you are seeing. Often, when folks only include the part of the traceback they think is useful, actual useful stuff is omitted.  And when you say *nothing* do you mean not even a blank line? If so, that makes me think you are not running the file you think you are running.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include *how* you are running the file.

Comment: If I were to run the code as is mentioned in the tread then I am getting result. However, If i change callable of map from int to int() I get the error message what you are mentioning which make sense since object of (int()) is not callable. So I think, you need to go back to your code and double check whether you are calling int or int(). You could also try a different expression to generate numlst = list(int(i) for i in str(number)) . Ofcourse, this not a solution to your problem rather to isolate the issue if it is at your current expression with generate numlst.